# arc web browser's window buttons always greyed out unless you hover over them. how can I fix this so they are always showing their color

Tags: macos

The "close, minimize, maximize" buttons on the arc browser are always greyed out and not colored. The colored buttons only show up when I hover over the buttons. Its like this while Arc is my active window. All my other apps window buttons are always colored when active but arc isn't. Is there any fix or reason to this?

Answer (score 2):

This is a choice the Arc developers have made.  I actually filed a bug with them in February about this, and they acknowledged it is confusing.  I suggest also filing a bug so they know it is important to users.  Hopefully they will fix it.  (In my case, since the time I filed the bug, I have moved back to Firefox.  Just passing along information to you.)

> Thank you for reaching out, so sorry for the confusion here
>
> Those buttons in the top left corner are greyed out by default and will show color when you hover over them. I can completely understand how this can be confusing!
>
> Will share this feedback on your behalf with the rest of the team

Comment: I have also repeatedly filed bugs. They could just add a configuration option to change this behaviour.